# Searching for multiple keywords in the same Outlook mail.item subject

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have multiple key words in the subject of an Outlook email. The key words are not in the same order every time but are present.

I have code that finds one of the key words but can't search for all key words.

How can I deal with the variances in case. Some email subjects are in upper some are in lower case and some mixed for example.

Tuf PHS Picking list: SD 19704802
TUF PHS PICKING LIST SD/19704796

I reviewed many threads. Some are helpful but I can't find a string combination that works for multiple key words in the subject.

```
Sub ExtractandPrintTufnelOders()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim myitem As Object
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim Unread As Long

Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.Folders("xxx@xxx.co.uk")
Set myInbox = myInbox.Folders("Inbox")
Set myitems = myInbox.Items
Found = False

For Each myitem In myitems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
    If myitem.Class = olMail Then

        If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Tuf" & "Picking List") > 0 Or _
          InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "TUF" & "PICKING LIST") > 0 Or _
          InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Tuf" & "Picking List:") > 0 Or _
          InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "tuf" & "picking list") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found a Tufnels Picking List"
            Found = True
            If Found = True Then
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next myitem

'If the subject isn't found:
If Not Found Then
'NoResults.Show
End If

'myOlApp.Quit
Set myOlApp = Nothing
Debug.Print myInbox.UnReadItemCount
End Sub
```

This doesn't find anything however if I reduce the string to just "Tuf" I get a positive result outputted.

Comment: Hint: the `&` operator here *concatenates* your two strings `"Tuf"` and `"Picking List"`. You'd need to use a logical `AND` to join multiple `IF` conditions. Also, you should sanitize case ahead of time so that you don't need to try and hardcode every possible spelling/capitalization permutation.

Comment: The `Restrict` is run each time in the `For Each` loop. You must extarct it outside of the loop.

Comment: And you need to use the `ci_phrasematch` restriction instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `&` operator here *concatenates* your two strings `"Tuf"` and `"Picking List"`. You'd need to use a logical `AND` to join multiple `IF` conditions. Also, you should sanitize case ahead of time so that you don't need to try and hardcode every possible spelling/capitalization permutation.

Change this:

```
If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Tuf" & "Picking List") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "TUF" & "PICKING LIST") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Tuf" & "Picking List:") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "tuf" & "picking list") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found a Tufnels Picking List"
                Found = True
                    If Found = True Then

                    End If
End If
```

To this:

```
Dim subj as String
subj = UCase(myItem.Subject) ' ignore casing
Found = (Instr(1, subj, "TUF") > 0) AND (Instr(1, subj, "PICKING LIST") > 0) 
If Found Then
    Debug.Print "Found a Tufnels Picking List"

End If
```

Here, we convert the subject to an all-upper-case string, this allows us to do a single comparison against upper-case "TUF" and upper-case "PICKING LIST", instead of trying to account for every variation of casing for these two substrings. We haven't actually manipulated `myItem.Subject` -- that still retains the original casing.

Comment: Thank David, i am currently looking into this. as i new to writting script i will reserch your advice. and report back. cheers!!

Comment: `InStr` is definitely not a solution.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it doesn't work for this case? Or that you simply prefer a *different* implementation?

Comment: I always suggest a better solution. And Outlook provides better tools for that.

Comment: That's fine, but it is simply incorrect to posit that `InStr` is "definitely not a solution". It *is* a solution, it *does work*, it *returns the correct/expected results*. It may not be the *only* or *best* solution, but it is absolutely *a solution*.

Comment: Nope, it checks for a specific case which is not applicable. There are a lot of possible scenarios in the case of the Subject line.

Comment: That is why I `UCASE`'d the subject string, in order to eliminate casing variations. This is fully explained in the answer above. This is a *very common* practice when comparing case-insensitive strings: compare everything as either lower or upper-case, rather than trying to handle every variation of mixed casing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can apply a filter to the subject as well and combine them together.

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'picking List'"
```

The `ci_phrasematch` restriction allows finding items with subject lines that contain every item from your list.

The [Items.Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) method applies a filter to the `Items` collection, returning **a new collection** containing all of the items from the original that match the filter. Here is a VB.NET sample code:

```
Private Sub RestrictUnreadItems(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim restrictCriteria As String = "[UnRead] = true"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim mail As Outlook._MailItem = Nothing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim item As Object = Nothing
    Try
        strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        folderItems = folder.Items
        resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria)
        item = resultItems.GetFirst()
        While Not IsNothing(item)
            If TypeOf (item) Is Outlook._MailItem Then
                counter += 1
                mail = item
                strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                     " - Subject: " + mail.Subject)
            End If
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)
            item = resultItems.GetNext()
        End While
        If (strBuilder.Length > 0) Then
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " _
                               + folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(folderItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems)
        If Not IsNothing(resultItems) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItems)
    End Try
End Sub
```

See [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) for more information.

So, basically your VBA code should look like that:

```
Dim unreadItems as Outlook.Items
Set unreadItems = myitems.Restrict("[Unread] = true")

For Each myitem In unreadItems
   If myitem.Class = olMail Then

     If InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Tuf" & "Picking List") > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "TUF" & "PICKING LIST") > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "Tuf" & "Picking List:") > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myitem.Subject, "tuf" & "picking list") > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Found a Tufnels Picking List"
                    Found = True
                        If Found = True Then

                        End If
      End If
   End If
Next
```

Comment: This is VB.NET sample which is very close to VBA.

Comment: thanks for your responce i have review simliar treads and will certainly do my homework here. it would seem are few different ways to tackle this. some more invovled than others.